# Java how to increase the value of doubles in a database table

Tags: java, sql, database, sql-update

I am having some trouble figuring out a query that will update values in a column in one of my tables. Below is my function:

```
public void increasePrice(String [] str) {

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("Update Journey Set price+=? where distance <?",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setDouble(1,Double.parseDouble(str[1]));
        ps.setDouble(2, Double.parseDouble(str[0]));          
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();
        System.out.println("1 rows updated.");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

To illustrate, the array passed in contains a value for distance and price and I am wanting to update the prices in the 'Journey' table based on their distance. For example, if a record in the table has a distance (type double) that is less than a given distance (the value of str[0]), I want to increase the price (also a double) of that record by the value 'str[1]' and do this for all records in the table.

The above code doesn't give any errors however, the records in the database never get updated. I could really use some help with this as I've searched around for a while now to try and find a solution and have not yet succeeded.

Comment: Silly question, but you do connection.commit() - right?

Comment: @Worthless yes I have implemented that and still no change

Comment: Well, what is the output of ps.executeUpdate()? It should tell you how many rows were affected.

Comment: @Worthless the problem is it doesn't like the syntax "+" and "<"

Comment: This would result in an exception, please post the exception stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what database you are using but my guess is that this line:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Update Journey Set price+=? where distance <?",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

should be written like this:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("Update Journey Set price=price+? where distance <?",PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

And not related to your question but the line

```
System.out.println("1 rows updated.");
```

may make you waste hours of debugging in the future because 0 or more rows can be actually updated.